# Artisan won't work in production but works fine locally

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am pulling my hair out over a problem in production: I cannot get my migrations to run. And, not only that but simply running 'php artisan' generates an error. The odd thing is that everything is working fine locally.

I am using Laravel 5.1 and have tried re-cloning my app on the server, re-installing vendor (after flushing the composer cache), redoing .env and giving permissions to the appropriate bootstrap/cache and storage files. I have also manually dropped all of my tables and then, when that didn't work, deleted and remade the database itself. I have run 'composer dump-autoload' many times as I tried to isolate the source of the problem with no luck.

I had a look at my log file and this is what comes up:

```
[2016-06-24 06:07:16] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /var/www/html/foobooks/app/Services/PrivacyService.php:157
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/foobooks/app/Services/PrivacyService.php(157): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/var/www/html/l...', 157, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/foobooks/app/Services/DateService.php(69): Foobooks\Services\PrivacyService->getPrivacyLevelIdWithPrivacyLevel('everyone')
#2 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(239): Foobooks\Services\DateService->Foobooks\Services\{closure}()
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cache\Repository->rememberForever('everyone_privac...', Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php(318): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(217): Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager->__call('rememberForever', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(217): Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager->rememberForever('everyone_privac...', Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/html/foobooks/app/Services/DateService.php(70): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('rememberForever', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/foobooks/app/Services/DateService.php(70): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::rememberForever('everyone_privac...', Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: Foobooks\Services\DateService->__construct(Object(Foobooks\Repositories\Models\DbEventRepository), Object(Foobooks\Services\PrivacyService), Object(Foobooks\$
#10 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(780): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Foobooks\...', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Foobooks\...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(220): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Foobooks\...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#15 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#16 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Foobooks\...', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Foobooks\...')
#18 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#19 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Foobooks\...', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Foobooks\...', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(115): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Foobooks\...')
#23 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->resolve('Foobooks\...')
#24 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(226): Illuminate\Console\Application->resolveCommands(Array)
#25 /var/www/html/foobooks/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->getArtisan()
#26 /var/www/html/foobooks/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 {main}
```

The app seems to be actually trying to instantiate my class DateService somewhere in the autoload process (which in turn instantiates PrivacyService) and this is what is causing the problem. I have searched my app for all instances where it is injected but none seem to be part of the autoloading process - and, it doesn't explain why things are working just fine locally.

Initially, when artisan complained, it gave me a 'missing base table error' and, for whatever reason, if I 'fake' created the table in database and then dropped it manually, the app moved on to complaining about another table until I did the manual create/drop again. I was able to move through table errors this way until I hit this 'Trying to get property of non-object' error.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem? It feels like there is some kind of database caching file that I don't know about that is hanging about somewhere and causing this problem, making the app think the migrations/seeds have already occurred. It just seems odd that creating fake tables and dropping them seemed to be doing something until this error popped up - also, odd that only the production environment is affected.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Is this the same error that you get on `php artisan`?

Comment: Yes - I get the same error just calling 'php artisan' as I do when calling 'php artisan migrate.' Something fundamental in the bootstrapping process seems to be going awry.

Comment: What's going on `Services/PrivacyService.php:157`

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: @UmbertP. Unfortunately, I get the same error when I run php artisan optimize.

Comment: Try composer install maybe?

Comment: @RossWilson (and others!) Thanks all, for trying to help! I figured it out. For some reason, the storage/framework/cache folder did not fully clear out when I flushed the production cache (for some reason, I think the permissions reverted so as to be inaccessible to the flush method - I need to figure out how that happened!). Then, I think those holdover cached folders were conflicting when artisan was bootstrapping. I reapplied permissions info to the cache, flushed it again, made sure everything was truly flushed and then I was able to run php artisan without a hitch - migrating and seeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: for some reason the permissions were different on some folders in my cache folder than others so the flush() method did not fully clear the cache. Legacy folders/files were conflicting with artisan's bootstrapping efforts. I was able to solve the problem by reapplying permissions to the storage/framework/cache directory, running flush() again. Once I did and made sure that ALL subfolders and files were deleted from the cache, I was able to run php artisan without a hitch.